# How to set the "Relational display column" as default in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have defined a number of relations between tables in my database. phpmyadmin offers a great function to display values rather than keys by specifying a display column in one table, then setting the table containing the foreign keys to show the "Relational display column" using the Options in browse view. I love this feature, but unfortunately the setting is not stored, and I can't find anywhere in the settings to make it default.

How can I set "Relational display column" as the default display view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It has been added in phpmyadmin 4.4: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/commit/bdce26898eaa20db72073e2cc7f7ece8625fd464

Add `$cfg['RelationalDisplay'] = 'D';`
to your `config.inc.php`